# Convert multiple table in excel(Each table contain diffrent column) to indivisual csv file as much table contain in Excel

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]

First I get the tables present in the Excel file

[image]

After I get the rows present in the table as per table name I put the table name dynamically from above step I get the table name and for each table I am trying to csv in automatic conversion its added two system generated Colum

[image]

As I have multiple table and different column in each table I cannot use custom option over there if I use custom option it will work for first iteration for second iteration it will not find the value in the table so its doesn't work I need to work dynamically

[image]

For second iteration its returning the same field but in second I am expecting second tables output
is there any solution for that I am providing the excel sheet for reference

[image]

[image]

Two table present in two different worksheet .

I tried to remove field but use custom csv table but its doesn't works because there may be possible there are n number of  column in each table and different field also .

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and received result using this methods.

I have created two table in different sheet with different column name, same as yours:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For each 2 :**

```
body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value']
```

I have used **`removeProperty`** function to remove property `"ItemInternalId"`.

**Compose 2 :**

```
removeProperty(json(string(outputs('Compose'))),'ItemInternalId')
```

we cannot remove property `"@odata.etag"` as it contains `.` in name so it throws error as shown below:

[image]

**Compose 3 :**

```
replace(string(outputs('Compose_2')), '"@odata.etag":"",','')
```

[image]

[image]

For work around converted the value of **Compose 2** in string and removed the `"@odata.etag"` and converted the Output in Json format again using **Parse JSON** connector.

**Parse JSON:**

```
{
    "type": "object",   
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Used **Create CSV table** connecter to create table.
I have used **`[]`** because it takes input as `Array`.

**`Output:`**

**`Table1:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**`Table2:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is an problem If the table contain n numbers of row it will create n number of csv . In a single csv its not adding all the row value.

Comment: @SHUVENDU I will check and update the answer.

Comment: @SHUVENDU, Unfortunately, AFAIK Currently It is not possible what you are looking for, only possible way I can see is using the Value of `List rows present in table` and create CSV table. In which you will also have `@odata.etag` and `ItemInternalId`.